# Convert binary string to .xls file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, js-xlsx

I have a 3rd party service which supposes to return me an .xls
By calling their API, I get a response similar to this:

[image]

Which I believe is a binary string (presented in Postman). The Content-Type is text/html; charset=utf-8

I need to convert it to .xls using node.js, so I try:

```js
let arr = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i != request.data.length; ++i)
    arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(request.data[i]);
    
let bstr = arr.join("");
var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
    type: "binary"
});

XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "output.xls");
```

This creates a file that opens without warnings, however, it does not display the contents correctly.

[image: created .xls file]

How can I create a valid .xls file from a given string using node.js? Why my solution is not working?

Comment: Did you come up with some solution for this?